# Python appending to a list when it shouldn't

Tags: python, python-2.7, scapy

For fun I'm making a simple script that sniffs on a network and logs the IP addresses and their mac addresses.

```
from scapy.all import *
import sys
import os

regestry = [['192.168.0.1','E8:DE:27:55:17:F4']]

def islocal(str):
    lst = str.split('.')
    if lst[0] == '192' and lst[1] == '168': 
        return True
    else:
        return False

def packatalize(packet):
    try:    
        dst = packet["IP"].dst
        if islocal(dst):
            var = False
            for reg in regestry:
                if dst not in reg:
                    print 'not in reg'
                    var = True
                elif dst in reg:
                    print 'in reg'
                    var = False
                    pass
            if var == True:
                print 'appending'
                regestry.append([dst,packet.dst])
                print regestry
                var = False

            else:
                pass    
        else:
            print 'not local'
            pass 
    except Exception as e: 
        print str(e)

sniff(prn=packatalize)

sys.exit()
```

This does what I want it to do, but for some reason it is appending these IP and MAC registries over and over even though they are already there.

Comment: This program should not even run. It does not declare the `regestry` variable anywhere. Can you provide the full source code, including the part where you declare the `regestry` variable?

Comment: What do you mean no reason? `regestry.append([dst,packet.dst])` clearly shows that it is being appended.

Comment: It does include the registry variable. It's the first line after the import statements.

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy "no reason" was a bad word choice. I meant to say "even though it shouldnt" I will by applying those edits now. :)

Comment: The `for reg in regestry:` loop processes the entire list, setting `var` on each iteration (and overwriting the previous value).  When you finally make it to the `if var == True` decision, `var` indicates only whether the _last_ item was in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For fun I'm making a simple script that sniffs on a network and logs
>   the IP addresses and their mac addresses.

Then may I suggest you use an appropriate data structure for your particular application? A `dict` seems good enough  though, because its keys are unique, i.e. **re-updating a mac address for an existing IP, would update the mac address in the registry instead of creating a new entry**.

```
>>> registry = {}
>>> registry['192.168.0.1'] = 'E8:DE:27:55:17:F4'
```

To use the dict:

```
>>> registry['192.168.0.2'] = 'E8:DE:27:55:17:F1'
>>> for ip, mac in registry.iteritems():
...     print ip, mac
... 
192.168.0.2 E8:DE:27:55:17:F1
192.168.0.1 E8:DE:27:55:17:F4
```

If you want your dictionary to maintain the insertion order, please meet [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

**If you want to use a set instead of simulating one with a list**

Instead of manually checking if a value is already in a list and only adding if it doesn't exist, you may use a set (which may be less error-prone than writing it yourself with your own Python code)

```
>>> registry = set()
```

This line creates a set, in your example it would be a list of "unique" values

```
>>> registry.add(('192.168.0.1','E8:DE:27:55:17:F4'))
```

This adds the value if it doesn't already exist.

Then to use it, it's not that much different from a list, e.g.

```
>>> registry.add(('192.168.0.2','E8:DE:27:55:17:F1'))
>>> for reg in registry:
...     print reg
... 
('192.168.0.1', 'E8:DE:27:55:17:F4')
('192.168.0.2', 'E8:DE:27:55:17:F1')
```

Please note though that the set doesn't maintain the insertion order.

Answer (score 3):

### You don't detect if item is in list

```
for reg in regestry:
    if dst not in reg:
        print 'not in reg'
            var = True
        elif dst in reg:
            print 'in reg'
            var = False
            pass
```

After this code is executed, 'var' is true iff the new item matched the *last* element of the list - it's overwritten at every iteration with the comparison result. The code after treats 'var' as if it indicated if the new item matched *any* item.

Perhaps you intended to use *break* instead of *pass* on that last line? That would fix this issue.